# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}u'(x)v(x)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}u(x)v'(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2xe^{-x^2}u(x)v(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}u'(x)v(x)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}u(x)v'(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2xe^{-x^2}u(x)v(x)dx$

for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ being polynomials. 
I have to prove also the convergence of the improper integrals.

---

As far as I know this is some kind of Gaußian integral. Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Comment: Hint: *integration by parts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the product rule we have,

$$\int (e^{-x^2}u'v+e^{-x^2}uv') dx=\int e^{-x^2} (uv)' dx$$

Now integrate by parts, integrating $(uv)'$ and differentiating $e^{-x^2}$, we get,

$$=uve^{-x^2}+\int uv2xe^{-x^2} dx$$

Put in bounds. If we show that $uve^{-x^2} \to 0$ for any polynomials $u$ and $v$  as $x \to \pm \infty$ we are done showing the equality of your integrals. $uv$ is a polynomial $a_0+a_1x^1+...+a_nx^n$ as polynomials are closed under multiplication and addition.

We can sow $e^{-x^2}x^n \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for all $n$ nonnegative integers by showing that for $x>0$ we have $e^x>\frac{x^n}{n!}>0$. This is trivial by the definition of $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then we can say $n!e^{-x^2+x}>x^ne^{-x^2}>0$ for $x>0$ and conclude by squeeze that $x^ne^{-x^2} \to 0$. By using limit sum, and the fact you can pull out constants from limits we must have $pe^{-x^2} \to 0$ for any polynomial $p$.

To show this approaches $0$ as $x \to -\infty$ use $x^ne^{-x^2}=\pm |x|^ne^{-|x|^2}$ for $x<0$.

Comment: but there is a 2x in the third one?

Comment: Yes thanks, I forgot that.

Comment: Can you explain the squeeze little bit more. Why it is n!e^{-x^2+x}->0?

Comment: $e^{x-x^2}=e^{x(1-x)} $ as $x \to \infty$ that quantity in the exponent approaches $-\infty$. So the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x(1-x)}$ is the same as $\lim_{u \to -\infty} e^u=0$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you have an idea how to show the convergence of the improper integrals? This should be the first step...

Comment: Hint: Use that $0<e^{-x^2}x^n<n! e^{-x^2}e^{x}=n! e^{-x^2+x}$ for $x>0$. To come up with convergence of $\int_{0^+}^{\infty} p(x) e^{-x^2}$ for any polynomial $p$.

Comment: Another hint: one can show that for $x\geq 2$ we have $-x^2+x>-x$ so that $e^{-x^2+x} \leq e^{-x}$ there. Use the comparison test for integrals.